# How to exit a nested loop and complete the program

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having a problem with my homework assignment, and I've hit a wall. I'm a fairly new programmer, and working through nested loops is confusing me. My program is running without breaking; however, after I enter a repeated number, every number that I enter after that isn't added to the list.

The assignment is to: 
" Write an application that inputs five numbers, each between 10 and 100, inclusive. As each number is read, display it only if it’s not a duplicate of a number already read. Provide for the “worst case,” in which all five numbers are different. Use the smallest possible array to solve this problem. Display the complete set of unique values input after the user enters each new value."

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] array = new int[5];
        int i = 0;
        int input = 0;
        boolean repeat = false;
        int placeHolder = 0;

        while(i < array.length) //While the number of inputs is less than the array length (5) Ask the user to input a number
        {
            System.out.printf("%s%d%s", "Please enter number", (i+1), ": ");
            input = scan.nextInt();

            if((input >= 10) && (input <= 100)) //Determine if the user input is in the range of 10-100
            {
                i++;
                for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) //Determine if the user input is a repeat
                {
                    if(input == array[x])
                    {
                        repeat = true;
                        System.out.println(input + " has already been entered.");
                    }
                }
                if(repeat == false) //If the user input isn't a duplicate - add it to the array
                    {
                        array[placeHolder] = input;
                        placeHolder++;
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid number! Please input a number between 10 and 100 (Inclusive)");
            }

            for(int y = 0; y < i; y++)
            {
                if(array[y] != 0)
                {
                    System.out.print(array[y] + " ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Once `repeat` is set to `true`, it'll never be set back to `false`, since you have no statement for doing that anywhere in the code. --- To fix, move `boolean repeat = false;` inside the `if` statement, next to `i++;`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `repeat` variable is never resetted back to `false`, causing the loop to never be exited.

To fix, you could reset it at the start of the every iteration of the loop:

```
if((input >= 10) && (input <= 100)) {
    repeat = false;  // <--- added here
    i++;
    for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {           
        if(input == array[x]){
            repeat = true;
            System.out.println(input + " has already been entered.");
        }
    }
    if(repeat == false) {
        array[placeHolder] = input;
        placeHolder++;
    }
}
```

That being said, it may not be within the scope of this school assignment, but in future you could use the `Set` object to make the code a lot shorter. This object will not accept duplicate values so you could keep adding numbers into it until it is 'full'.

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements

Documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

In addition, you can look at using `if(!repeat)` instead `if(repeat==false)`. At least for me, with the combination of that coding style + a good boolean variable name, it sort of makes it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

In the vast majority of cases a "break" out of nested loops indicates a design flaw. Not in every case, so:

a) Java has a break command that does just that: break out of a loop/block:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    for(;;){
        while(){
           break finished;
        }
        if(somecondition){
            break finished;
        }
    }
    finished:
       // here we end up whenever we break out.
}
```

b) A simple return does the job:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    for(;;){
        while(){
           return;
        }
        // ...
        if(somecondition){
           return;
        }
    }
}
```

maybe in an additional method:

```
boolean worker(){
    for(;;){
        while(){
           return true;
        }
        // ...
        if(somecondition){
           return false;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    boolean result = worker();
    //do some finalizing or evaluate the result.
}
```

c) break out of the program:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    for(;;){
        while(){
           System.extit(0); //success
        }
        // ...
        if(somecondition){
           System.extit(1); //some error
        }
    }
}
```

A further way are Exceptions - which allways indicate error.

What you choose depends.

a) Often found in a parser

b) is very common if there is an actual function that  you deliver(it comes as natural if you code a part of program: once you have the result you return)

c) is common in applications, maybe wrapped a special exit method that does some additional cleanup.

In your case, the choice is up to you and maybe you rethink if you realy want to break out(text doesn't sound like it).

(remark: this is a straight and general answer to the question in the title: "How to exit a nested loop and complete the program")